# Meteor Audit-Argument-Checks Error

Tags: meteor, coffeescript

I'm getting an error "Did not check() all arguments". But I am checking all the arguments - very strange.

This Coffeescript code throws an error when you run the method:

```
Meteor.methods
  doSomething : ( arg={} )-> 
    check arg, Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out to be the argument default. The following code works:

```
Meteor.methods
  doSomething : ( arg )-> 
    check arg, Match.Maybe( Object )
    arg ?= {}
```

This only seems to be a problem when you use empty object as an argument default. Other kinds of default argument seem to work - I tested null and list.

There's also a difference between calling:

```
Meteor.call "doSomething"
```

And calling this...

```
Meteor.call "doSomething", undefined
```

In the first case the argument is implicitly undefined, and will be set to a default. This bug does NOT happen.

In the second case we explicitly pass undefined (or null) and we get this bug. If you can avoid doing this, you won't need to change your arg defaults.